# Android query to extract first word from a field

Tags: android, string, sqlite

So I've been dragging with this one for some time now and simply can't find the solutions

Let's say I have a table called NAME with values like
John Doe
Jane Doe 
etc.

I just want to pull the first word.... so everything after the first space ' ' will not show
I'm pulling the data into a Cursor as it's over 2000 records

Any thoughts on a raw query that will do such a thing?
Thanks in advance
Yeshai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just get the string from db as a string and use something like

```
String[] strs = dbString.split(" ");

str[0] should be what you need.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but i'm not sure how I would split this as I'm getting the data from the DB into a Cursor (sorry I didn't mention that)
As well I'm talking about 2000+ lines for each query